# cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.5

I am trying to pip install tensorflow but I keep getting this error, it works fine with python 3.7 but doesn't on this version of python. Does anyone know why?

File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 384, in compile
raise CompileError(msg)
distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'D:\VS\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

---

ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio
Running setup.py clean for grpcio